# Redirect to a new Tab on click of a link

Tags: jsf

I am working on JSF. I have a requirement like this. When I click a link it should open the target  in a new tab. But the target page does not reside inside my project. It is a seperate application.

I tried a href, h:link nothing is working.
This is what i tried finally. But its again and again opens the same page in new tab.

```
    <h:commandLink value="#{item.title}" target="http://localhost:89/kordil_edms/documents.php" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this -

```
 <a href="http://localhost:89/kordil_edms/documents.php" target="_blank"> Open </a>
```

Comment: thnx! change ur username from default user name.